# How can I convert an HtmlAttribute to a string?

Tags: c#, html, web-scraping, href, tostring

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(page);

var Articles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@class = 'b-product-grid-tile js-tile-container']"); 
var href = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]");

foreach (HtmlNode link in href)
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];
                _entries.Add(new EntryModel { Link = att });

                // att.ToString(); <----- Want to convert the HtmlAttribute to a string.
            }
```

Full Code of my Scraper:

[image: Full Code of my Scraper]

EntryModel List:

[image: EntryModel List]

Main Window:

[image: Main Window]

The links I need:

[image: The links I need]

Comment: Hi welcome! Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) over at the help center. We would greatly appreciate you putting the code that is involved with the question directly into the post, instead of posting images to the code. This is so we can assist you more effectively.

Comment: If you want the value, you can just do `link.Attributes["href"].Value` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @DekuDesu ty i will look into it (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be using the `System.Web.Mvc.TagBuilder` class:

```
var attributes = new { @class = "myClass", id = "elId" };

var tag = new TagBuilder("href");
tag.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(attributes));

return tag.ToString();
```